# Best way for checkForToastMessage (working example included)

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

After fumbling around for several hours, we found this following solution.
It's hard to image that this should be the ideal way. Now I would like to know, how the protractors intended way should look like.

```
checkForToastMessage(expectedMessageText: string) {
    browser.wait(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        return element(by.cssContainingText('.message-title', expectedMessageText)).isPresent()
            .then(function(isPresent) {
                if (!isPresent) {
                    $(".message-title").getText().then(function (text) {
                        console.log("found: " + text)
                    }) 
                }
                browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
                return isPresent;
            });
    }, 2000, "There was no Toast with the message '" + expectedMessageText + "' to display!");
}

checkForNoToastMessage() {
    var timeout = 2000;
    var start = 0;
    while (start <= timeout) {
        browser.sleep(100);
        start += 100;
        browser.wait(function () {
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            return element(by.css('.message-title')).isPresent()
                .then(function(isPresent) { 
                    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
                    expect(isPresent).toBeFalsy("no toaster was expected");
                    return true;
                });
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can easily find the toaster popup presence on UI in protractor with help of ***protracot.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf()*** method. It works perfectly. We don't need such a lengthy logic.

You can follow the working example below:

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var ToasterPopUP = element(by.css('.message-title'));

EC.visibilityOf(ToasterPopUP ).call().then(function(isPresent){
    expect(isPresent).toBeFalsy("no toaster was expected");
  });
```

Comment: Property 'call' does not exist on type 'Condition<{}>'